# MVC site 'Caching' Issue

Tags: html, model-view-controller, iis-7, umbraco7

I'm not sure of the best way to explain this but here goes, I've got quite a few issues on my site an example is the following:

A user logs in and goes through the authorization process as expected, where the login button now changes to logout and secure pages are shown to the user however when the user logs out running the following simple code:

```
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();
        return Redirect("/");
```

The only thing that appears to happen is that the user is redirected back to the home page but still appears to be signed in (the logout button is still visible). Pressing F5 has no effect but if I go into Dev tools (on Chrome) and hard reload the page and THEN press the logout button then the user can log out successfully but if they sign in again then the error reappears.

This section of the site hasn't been touched in months but this behaviour started to manifest itself a couple of months ago and exists on all browsers.

Has anyone seen this type of behaviour before?

This is an Umbraco MVC 4 site running in IIS 7.5

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use iis session state setting.

[image]

If you want to prevent IIS from caching content on the server-side(output caching), you could go to IIS manager->site node->output  caching->edit feature settings->uncheck enable cache.

```
<system.webServer>

    <caching enabled="false" />
```

another way is by using HTTP response header:

1)Open iis manager.

2)Select the site and click on the "HTTP response header feature".

[image]

3)Click on the set common header link from the action pane.

4)click the checkbox "expire web content" and select "immediately" radio button.

[image]

make sure enabled the application pool recycling in iis.

links:

[IIS Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching)

[Client Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache)

[Recycling Settings for an Application Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall give these a go and report back :)

Comment: Hi, Jalpa, sadly not I've tried both of your suggestions above and the site still appears to be caching results